# javascript datepicker format

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using a `datepicker` in my application.

```
this.$el.find('#ondue').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+2M",
       // altFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function(x) {

            return self.onDate(x);

             },

        beforeShow: function() {
            return $('#ondue').datepicker("option", "maxDate", $("#returndue").datepicker('getDate'));
        }
      });
```

In the UI I want to show the date in the format: `DD/MM/YYYY`

and send to the server in the format: `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, but when you will post data to the server, convert the date from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY on server side wrt to server side language which you are using & then save the data.

Comment: Actually with that format( MM/DD/YYYY ), i had lot of calculations in the client side only...

So is there any possibility to show only DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: First, get this date from input & use this code [ var myDate = $("#ondue").val();   //  which will be as your ui format DD/MM/YYYY';
var dateSplit = myDate.split('/');

var formattedDate = dateSplit[1]+'/'+dateSplit[0]+'/'+dateSplit[2]; ]  to convert to specified format